# Simply getting fields from django query set

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

```
class Question(models.Model):
  question_text = ...

class Answer(models.Model):
  question = models.ForeignKey ...
  user = models...
```

Basically, what I'm trying to do is return the set of questions that have been unanswered by the user.  So basically, lets say answers = Answer.objects.exclude(user=my_user), i need to somehow do Question.objects.filter(id__in=answers.question.id).  This last statement is obviously not going to work, but I hope you can get the idea.

Appreciate any help on this. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Question.objects.exclude(id__in=[answer.question.id for answer in Answer.objects.filter(user='Joe')])
```

Comment: That's the right idea, but it's pretty inefficient because of the fact that you're getting the whole Answer object and its related Question just to get the question id. Better is this:   `Question.objects.exclude(id__in=Answer.objects.filter(user='Joe').values_list('question_id'))`

Comment: Thanks. Didn't know about `values_list`.

Comment: Thanks to both of you! I'd upvote each but don't have the street cred, apparently.